# Can structs be compared with hashes or dictionaries

Tags: c++, c, dictionary, hash, struct

I have been trying to understand the use of structs in C to have a better understanding on programming concepts in general and structs are some how confusing to me; it's easy to learn the syntax but hard to determine why and when to use them, I got to the point to believe that structs are just one more tool in the C programming language since it looks like you could accomplish anything you want without really having to use structs. Again, this is what I think so far since I don't fully understand them.

Besides creating a unique data-type with structs what would be the difference between structs and hashes/dictionaries?

What would be the main benefit of choosing structs?

Does it make sense to think about structs as hashes or dictionaries?

Again, I'm just trying to have a better understanding about concept of structs in C.

Thanks

Comment: Please choose one language to ask about, either C or C++. They are different languages, and structs are different in them. In C, they are simply data. In C++, they may have active components (methods) and more complicated semantics. If you need to ask about both languages, then use separate questions. When you have decided, please remove the other tag and edit the question to specify the language.

Comment: Thinking that some feature doesn't have use is common among new learners. I've heard some friend of my saying that OOP is useless or design pattern is useless and even pointers and callbacks are useless. If you think that way, is because you haven't yet overcame any programming questions large scaled enough. Just keep in mind, every feature in any popular programming language has it's meaning because the creators of them are not idiots, on the contrary, they're genius.

Comment: @TwilightSun: I was totally with you until you said that *every* feature has a meaning. Some features are widely acknowledged to have been mistakes, or are explicitly stated to be present only because of backward-compatibility.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: There's no reason to compulsively say "C is not C++" just because you've seen both tags at a time. The idea of structures and classes is similar in C and C++. This is a good question from someone who thinks about how OOP is done in other languages. While the fields of structures (read it as: classes) are known at compile-time, the keys of hashmaps aren't, which makes it similar to classes in languages like Python. Actually, I like this question. It's the question of someone who already knows a language and compares the new language with the ones she's already familiar with.

Comment: @ruakh Well, I had to admit that you may be right. But the author of the language definitely wanted to solve some problem by adding a feature, it just might not turn out to be as perfect as the author thought in the first place.

Comment: @mafso: I did not object to having both tags “just because” both were present, and it is a straw man to suggest it. As my comment states, structs are different in C and C++. The answers should be different for each language, and they should not be conflated because that dilutes the search results for people seeking answers for one language specifically.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, they are different, no question about that. But the basic idea is the same (as opposed to the way how classes are implemented in languages like Python). The differences between C and C++ structs are actually syntactic sugar. This isn't a question about programming style, idioms or anything similar; it's a question about how C/C++ structs are similar to hashmaps. The differences between C and C++ don't matter here at all!

Comment: @EricPostpischil: People who are thinking about this question may be interested in the answers given here, no matter whether they want to write C or C++ code.

Comment: Could any of the downvoters be so good to give an explanation? I can't see any problem with that question...

Comment: "'Questions asking for code must demonstrate […]'" — this question is asking for code? Honi soit qui mal y pense…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it make sense to think about structs as hashes or dictionaries?

No, they are neither. Introducing hashes/dictionaries only muddies the water; in fact, neither C nor C++ provide hashes/dictionaries (though the C++ standard library provides some containers that make use of hashing, and maps could be called "dictionaries").

In C++, structs are classes, so the question you should be asking is "what is the benefit of a class?"

The answer to this question can be found very easily on the internet and in your C++ book (which I suggest you read now!) but, in brief, classes:

- group data into one object
- group operations
- allow encapsulation for safety

At the very simplest level, ask yourself whether you would want to pass around 10 integers to lots of functions, repetitively, or group them into a single object and send that one.

In C, the grouping of data is pretty much all you get from structs, but that's still very useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is a conceptual similarity between structs/classes in C/C++ and hash tables/dictionaries. In both cases, values are associated with "keys" and can be accessed using the "key" value. However, the two things are different in one very important respect:

> Structs/classes map data and functions (whether through pointers or as methods) to identifiers provided by the programmer in the source code while hash tables/dictionaries map data to key values provided by the user of the compiled code, either directly or indirectly.

The consequence of this distinction is that the compiler replaces the identifiers provided by the programmer with memory addresses and offsets at compile-time -- slightly more complicated in the case of dynamically allocated objects. Users of the compiled code cannot add or remove members of structs/classes. In the case of hash tables/dictionaries, the users of the compiled code can typically add and remove members -- though not always, depending on what the programmer has provided -- and various hashing or indexing methods are evaluated at run-time to update or access members of the hash table/dictionary.

Still, while there is a conceptual similarity, programmers are trying to develop very different solutions when using either mechanism in C or C++ and will almost never encounter a situation which calls for choosing between a struct/class or hash table/dictionary. The need and use cases for each are sufficiently different to ensure that kind of a choice will never trouble a programmer in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a program that maintains a list of students at a school.  The students will have names, addresses, dates of birth, classes they're enrolled in etc..  You could put each of these things in separate containers (probably hash tables or balanced binary trees, sorted arrays if they don't change much) keyed on their student id, but then you'd have to find them all separately and access lots of pages of memory to get all the information for a single student.  Using structures, you can effectively say "store all this information together", then put the struct of such fields into a single place in an array or hash table.

In C++ they're more powerful as you can use Object Oriented/Orientated Programming to force people to use a particular set of functions to interact with the data, which helps you keep it - and even related data outside the struct - in a consistent, valid state.  (OOP has other functionality too, but that's the most relevant and fundamental here).

Comment: Thank you all for the good explanations, it starting to make sense, I thought I had read enough to have a good understanding but aparently NOT, I will look into it deeply. Thanks a lot.